# Eigenvectors of the $2\times2$ zero matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

I have been given a problem that involves the following matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 0\\0 & -2\end{bmatrix}$$

I calculated the eigenvalues to be $\lambda_{1,2} = -2$

When I go to calculate the eigenvectors I get the following system:

$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

The eigenvectors are clearly $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ and any multiple of these

But why is this? Is there a formal reasoning or method why it's only these two? Why doesn't $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ exist as an eigenvector?

Thank you

Comment: You must have misstated the problem.  The eigenvalues of the matrix you gave us are $-2$ (with multiplicity $2$).  $\pmatrix{1\cr 1\cr}$ is a perfectly good eigenvector.

Comment: Any vector is an eigenvector.

Comment: Maybe because $\left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\1\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\0\end{array}\right) + \left(\begin{array}{c}0 \\1\end{array}\right)$ ! I mean linear combination ;)

Comment: When questions like these ask for eigenvectors, what they actually want are all the linearly independent eigenvectors. This way, it's easier to figure out what the eigenspace (the set of all eigenvectors). In this question, the eigenspace is the set of all vectors, because any $v = \pmatrix{x\cr y\cr}$ will satisfy $Av = -2v.$ So you want two eigenvectors that form a basis for the eigenspace, and the easiest combination is $\pmatrix{1\cr 0\cr}$ and $\pmatrix{0\cr 1\cr}.$ But you could also have say, $\pmatrix{1\cr 1\cr}$ and $\pmatrix{20\cr 1\cr}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvalues are not $\pm1$.  You might want to have another go at that.
The procedure for eigenvectors gives those two vectors.  They form a basis for the eigenspace.  Since they have the same eigenvalue, any linear combination of them is also an eigenvector.  Including $[1,1]^T$.

Comment: Ooops, I meant $-2,2$, I will edit that now.

Comment: My textbook gave the answers down as just the first two that I mentioned, and made no further mentions of anything, so I was confused as to whether [1,1] or any multiple of it would be an eigenvector

Answer (score 1):

A number $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$ iff $\det (A - \lambda I) = 0$. If $A$ denotes the matrix under consideration, we have $\det (A - \lambda I) = 0$ iff $\lambda = -2$, so $\lambda := -2$ is the eigenvalue of $A$. By definition, a nonzero vector $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ iff $Av = \lambda v$, *i.e.* iff $(-2v_{1},-2v_{2}) = (-2v_{1},-2v_{2})$, so every eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$ is a linear combination of the vectors $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$.

Comment: $(-2v_{1},-2v_{2}) = (-2v_{1},-2v_{2})$ does not imply $v_1 = v_2,$ which seems to be what you are saying when you wrote the eigenvectors are of the form $t(1,1).$

Comment: Yes, of course, thanks. @dhk628

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is a square matrix. Then $A$ is a multiple of the identity **iff**
every vector is an eigenvector of $A$.

If $A$ is a multiple of the identity, then $A = \alpha I$ for some $\alpha$ and hence $Av = \alpha v$ for any $v$.

Now suppose for any non zero $v$ there is some $\lambda_v$ such that we have $Av = \lambda_v v$. Choose $u,v$ to be linearly independent, then
$A u = \lambda_u u, Av = \lambda_v v, A(u+v) = \lambda_{u+v} (u+v)=\lambda_u u + \lambda_v v$. It
follows from linearity and independence that $\lambda_v = \lambda_{u+v} = \lambda_u$, and hence that $Av = \lambda_u v$ for all $v$.