# Is there $2 \times 2$ symmetric matrix with eigenvectors $u, v$ where the angle between $u$ and $v$ is not $π/2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there $2 \times 2$ symmetric matrix with eigenvectors $u, v $ where the angle between $u$ and $v$ is not $π/2$?

In other words, where the dot product between $u$ and $v$ is not $0$?

Comment: this depends if the corresponding eigenvalues are the same or not

Comment: If the eigenvalues are distinct, then the eigenspaces are necessarily orthogonal. If the eigenvalues are the same, then any two non-parallel vectors in the plane will do.

Answer (score 3):

A matrix being symmetric implies that $v\cdot (Aw) = (Av)\cdot w$ for any two vectors $v, w$. If $v$ and $w$ are eigenvectors of $A$ with different eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$, we get
$$
\lambda_1(v\cdot w) = (\lambda_1 v)\cdot w = (Av)\cdot w = v\cdot (Aw) = v\cdot(\lambda_2w) = \lambda_2(v\cdot w)
$$
and since $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2$, we must have $v\cdot w = 0$.

Comment: This common place provides hardly an answer.

Comment: On the contrary, it is a very good hint.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe What does your comment really mean? That my answer is not detailed enough? I'd say yours is worse. That we shouldn't give answers? That's a losing battle.

Comment: Well, "commonplace" is a synonym to truism, bathos, banality, platitude.

Comment: @Arthur Isn't it a commonplace that eigenvectors to different eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are orthogonal?  In your answer you've proved that fact which we all -- the OP included, I presume -- know.  Cui bono?  Instead of proving well known facts I've just gave an example...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I would think that the OP hasn't seen this fact neither stated nor proven, as evidenced by the fact that they ask this question.

Comment: @Arthur In that case the OP or her instructor did something seriously wrong.  But that's reading the tee leaves.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Or they just haven't gotten that far yet. I'd think that was a more probable reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48975/discussion-between-michael-hoppe-and-arthur).

Comment: @Arthur Agreed, so it was much ado about nearly nothing.

Answer (score 2):

If the eigenvalues $\lambda_u$ and $\lambda_v$ of $u$ and $v$ are different, it's impossible. Because,

$\left< u,Av \right>= \lambda_v\left<u,v\right>$

and $\left<Au,v\right>= \lambda_u\left< u ,v \right>$.

But,$\left< u,Av \right>=\left< Au,v \right>$.

So $(\lambda_u- \lambda_v)\left<u,v\right>=0$.

And $\left<u,v\right>=0$

Comment: yeah but its there any example matrix?

Answer (score 0):

The only matrices fulfilling your condition are multiples of $$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
In this case $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ are not orthogonal linear independent eigenvectors.

Edit: calculating the characteristic polynomial of $$\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\b&c\end{pmatrix}$$
its discriminant is $$(a-c)^2+4b^2.$$
Hence the matrix possesses only one eigenvalue iff $b=0$ and $a=c$.

Comment: it only gives eiganvectors [1 0] and [0 1 ]. Doesn't meet condtion

Comment: Not only, but also.  Clearly $(3,42)$ and $(2001,-\pi)$ are linear independent eigenvectors belonging to eigenvalue $1$, which are not othogonal.  Nevertheless, you might find also orthogonal eigenvectors, but there are others.  Generally speaking, eigenvectors of symmetric matrices to the same eigenvalue may not be orthogonal.  Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443154/eigenvectors-of-the-2-times2-zero-matrix?rq=1

Comment: Couldn't  identity matrix have every vector as its eigenvector because $Iv= 1v$?

Comment: Except the zero-vector,  yes.